# f:ajax listener not fired. Unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I got stuck with this problem. I wrap two tables inside of a h:form. I also tried to wrap nested tables in different h:form tags. So my goal is a listener to get fired in the server side when a user click a check box. I use execute="@this" because I don't want to sent all the inputs.... The javascript event in onevent attribute gets fired, but NEVER the listener in the sever. I can see a request is sent to the sever, when I click the checkbox. I don't know why it doesn't get called.

VIEW:

```
  <h:form>
                <table id="trades">
                    <th class="image_cell"></th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Portfolio</th>
                        <ui:repeat var="trade" value="#{controller.errorTrades}">
                            <tr class="trade error">
                                <td class="image_cell error"><h:graphicImage styleClass="expandable" url="resources/images/plus.png"></h:graphicImage></td>
                                <td id="type" class="error">#{trade.type}</td>
                                <td class="error">#{trade.portfolio}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="operations">
                                <td id="#{trade.murexId}" class="operation_row" colspan="4">
                                        <table id="operations">
                                            <tr class="header">
                                                <th class="empty_cell"></th>
                                                <th class="operation_cell">Operation</th>
                                                <th>Time Transaction</th>
                                                <th>Comment</th>
                                                <th id="delete">Delete</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <ui:repeat var="operation" value="#{trade.operationsSortList}">
                                                <tr class="operation">
                                                    <th class="empty_cell"></th>
                                                    <td id="operation" class="operation_cell color">#{operation.operation}</td>
                                                    <td class="color">#{operation.time}</td>
                                                    <td class="color">#{operation.coment}</td>
                                                    <td class="color checkbox">
                                                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="delete">
                                                            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="click" listener="#{controller.onDelete}" onevent="onDeleteProcess" />
                                                            <f:attribute name="murexId" value="#{trade.murexId}" />
                                                            <f:attribute name="operationId" value="#{operation.id}" />
                                                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                                              
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </ui:repeat>
                                        </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ui:repeat>
                </table>
            </h:form>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@ViewScoped
public class Controller 
{
    private ArrayList trades;
    private ArrayList errorTrades = new ArrayList();

    .......code

    public boolean onDelete(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) 
    {
        long murexId = 0;
        BigDecimal operationId = null;
        boolean result = false;
        Trade trade;
        Iterator itop;
        Operation operation;
        ......code

        return true;
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: The ajax listener method should return `void`. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: What JSF impl/version are you using? Early Mojarra versions have some peculiar problems with nested `<ui:repeat>`s. Try with `<h:dataTable>`  instead to exclude the one and other.

Comment: I think it works if it returns boolean, but it doesn't work even if I use void. I'm using JSF 2.1. I'm using a lot of css and it's easier to implement it with <ui:repeat>. Any idea?

Comment: That's not specific enough. "JSF 2.1" is a specification version. It doesn't tell anything about the implementation used (Mojarra, MyFaces, etc) nor its version (2.1.0, 2.1.1, etc). Even though I bet that it's Mojarra given the fact that MyFaces has a much more solid implementation of `<ui:repeat>` tag. By the way, to post comment replies on posts which are not the commenter's own, don't forget to include `@nickname`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting familiar with JSF and its implementations... But yeah, it's Mojarra no MyFaces. Good to know that <ui:repeat> has better implementation with MyFaces. Thanks! @BalusC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALMOST SOLVED**

I got it working. I wrap the second ui:repeat with h:form and the I **use** execute="@form" instead of execute="@this". That's why I put "almost solved"... Any idea why this happens?

```
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat var="operation" value="#{trade.operationsSortList}">
              <tr class="operation">
                   <th class="empty_cell"></th>
                   <td id="operation" class="operation_cell color">#{operation.operation}</td>
                   <td class="color">#{operation.time}</td>
                   <td class="color">#{operation.coment}</td>
                   <td class="color checkbox">
                       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox title="delete">
                             <f:ajax execute="@this" event="click" listener="#{controller.onDelete}" onevent="onDeleteProcess" />
                             <f:attribute name="murexId" value="#{trade.murexId}" />
                             <f:attribute name="operationId" value="#{operation.id}" />
                      </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                                              
                   </td>
             </tr>
     </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Thanks for your support!